# InstallShield 2018 Professional Edition

Tags: installshield

I'm using Basic MSI project in InstallShield 2018 Professional Edition. I have created multiple Instances and would like to have multiple services (each service for each instance) and the service should start when the new instance is getting created.

How can i pass the following Windows command in Command line Argument of installshield to create Service.

(sc create servicename binpath= "path" DisplayName = "name"start = auto)

Is the above requirement possible with the basic msi project? If yes, then how? Kindly help.

Also is it possible for User to enter the service name and this name should get append with the predefined Service name?(maybe as a pop-up)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the commandline, you can pass in some properties and have a custom action (installscript, c#, etc...) and use these properties when running sc.exe to create the service.

You can certainly add new dialogs or modify existing ones to take in User parameters for the services you want to create, but this requires a bit more work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still struggling to create services but I have achieved User-based Service name by adding new Dialog. Can you please give me some hint what kind of properties I must pass from the commandline ? Is it not possible to do directly from installShield without using Commandline ?